# Angular2 array of interfaces is defined on initializing and undefined later

Tags: typescript, angular

I am writing a program that reads from a .csv file, cast the information into an interfaces and then pushes each interface into an array.

When initializing the array, everything is correct and logging the array gives me expected results. The problem is the array is either empty or undefined when called later.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CSVService {
  public csv: any;
  public allPlayers: Player[];
  public text: string;
  public player: Player;

  constructor() {
    this.readFile();
  }

  public readFile(){
      let rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
      rawFile.open("GET", "../../data.csv", true);
      this.splitCSV(rawFile);
      rawFile.send(null);
  }

  public splitCSV(rawFile){
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(rawFile.status === 200){
            let allTextLines = rawFile.responseText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
            allTextLines.shift();
            var persons: Array<Player> = [];
            for(let item of allTextLines){
              var person = [];
              person = item.split(',');
              this.player = {
                name: person[0],
                serve_accuracy: +person[1],
                serve_spin: +person[2],
                return_skill: +person[3],
                return_accuracy: +person[4],
                return_spin: +person[5],
                notes: person[6]
              }
              persons.push(this.player);
            }
            persons.pop();

        }
        this.allPlayers = persons;
        console.log(this.allPlayers);
    }
  }

  public status(){
    console.log(this.allPlayers);
  }
}

export interface Player {
name: string,
serve_accuracy: number,
serve_spin: number,
return_skill: number,
return_accuracy: number,
return_spin: number,
notes: string,
}
```

If I call the status method later in the program, I am given and undefined.

Comment: Do you always call `status` after the operation is done? As you're doing it using http it's async so if you call it before the request is done then it might explain what you're getting. If that's not the case, then try to do: `console.log(this, this.allPlayers);` in your `status` method and check what it prints for `this`

Comment: status is called on a click event, the array is initialized when the class is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your `rawFile.onreadystatechange = function(){...}` with arrow function `rawFile.onreadystatechange = () => {...}` and the line `this.player = ...` will refer to the instance of your service. That is a problem

Comment: Worked, but can you explain why? Is it a scope issue, with that block of code being inside a function?

Comment: Because inside your regular `onreadystatechange` function `this` refers to the instance of XHR object, for whom this method belongs.
Basics of JS )